# ansible aws_s3 throwing error when copy files from s3 to target server

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

I'm trying to copy a file from s3 bucket to a target server using ansible and here is my playbook

```
- name: Copy file to server
  hosts: targetserver

  vars:
    region: "us-west-2"
    s3_path: "{{First}}/{{Last}}/Testfile"
    target_path: '"C:\Users\testuser\Downloads"'

  tasks:
    - name: Get file from S3
      amazon.aws.aws_s3:      #(tried using s3_object and just aws_s3 as well)
        bucket: test-files
        object: "{{ s3_path }}"
        dest: "{{ target_path }}"
        mode: get
```

I keep getting this error

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The module amazon.aws.aws_s3 was redirected to amazon.aws.s3_object, which could not be loaded."}

I have the aws packages installed for it

```
ansible-galaxy collection list

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible_collections

Collection                   Version
amazon.aws                    7.0.0  
ansible.netcommon             5.3.0
```

here is my ansible configuration

```
ansible --version
ansible [core 2.16.1]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/Users/heidi/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/heidi/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /opt/homebrew/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.12.0 (main, Oct  5 2023, 15:44:07) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/bin/python)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Am i missing something here?